# How do I get a domain link to open my app on android?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

The following works fine:

I click on the link `www.mycompany.com` in an email and it starts my app:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="www.mycompany.com/download" android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

However, what I want to work is as below but it's not working:

I want to be able to restrict it to the link `www.mycompany.com/download`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="www.mycompany.com/download" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Why the distinction? I don't want to block my entire website with the app. I just want that specific domain to redirect to the app. How do I do that?

Comment: `host` are same in both code snippet.I guess it is just typo.kindly have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

What you've shown is not a subdomain. That is,

```
www.mycompany.com/download
```

is *not* a subdomain of

```
www.mycompany.com
```

But you could use a subdomain to address this issue by setting up something like

```
download.mycompany.com
```

and have it map to `www.mycompany.com/download`. (Most servers allow you to set up subdomains like that.) You can then modify the intent filter accordingly.

**EDIT**

To support what you're trying to do without setting up a subdomain, you can do the following:

```
<data
    android:host="www.mycompany.com"
    android:scheme="http"
    android:pathPrefix="download"
/>
```

Comment: I remove the word "sub-domain". Is there a way to do what I want with my current setup? That is, through the `www.mycompany.com/download`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try latest feature made available by Google and that is **[App-indexing](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/)** to show your app even when user search about your website on Google.

You need to go through **2 steps**:

**1** Sign Up for this feature [here](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1itcqPAQqggJ6e4m8aejWLM8Dc5O8P6qybgGbKCNxGV0/viewform)

**2** Update your app as well as sitemap of your website as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/details)

For further reference you can go through [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/index.html)

**Screenshot :**

[image]